# how to convert date into utc milliseconds with timezone in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

`getTime()` Is it return local or UTC milliseconds?

```
var startDate = new Date(); 
var val = (startDate.getTime()).toString();
```

Below logic will return UTC millisecords:

```
var startDate = new Date(); 
var val = (new Date(Date.UTC(
    startDate.getFullYear(),
    startDate.getMonth(),
    startDate.getDate(),
    startDate.getHours(),
    startDate.getMinutes(),
    startDate.getSeconds()
))).getTime().toString();
```

Need script for converting the date to UTC milliseconds with timezone like `America/Los_Angeles`

Comment: rather than re-inventing the wheel - you may want to look at [moment timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) ... *shh, don't tell anyone I gave you a link to an external library*

Comment: [`getTime: A number representing the milliseconds elapsed between 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC and the given date.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)

Comment: `Need script for converting the date to UTC milliseconds with timezone like America/Los_Angeles`. What do you mean? UTC is the same time all around the world. Can you give some actual examples of your starting data and what you are expecting?

Comment: Why have you marked this question with the jQuery tag? `jQuery is a popular cross-browser JavaScript library that facilitates DOM (Document Object Model - HTML Structure) traversal, event handling, animations, and AJAX interactions by minimizing the discrepancies across browsers and providing an easy-to-use API.`

Answer (score 1):

Here you create a new date:

```
var startDate = new Date();
```

This is set to your browsers current timezone, here mine is Turkey:

```
Fri Sep 02 2016 17:50:06 GMT+0300 (Turkish Summer Time)
```

If you convert this string `Fri Sep 02 2016 17:50:06 GMT+0300` into millis then you will have the value with the GMT+0300:

```
Date.parse("Fri Sep 02 2016 17:50:06 GMT+0300")
>> 1472827806000
```

Here, you can create your date object with a different timezone and get the millis of it, let's say it is `America/Los_Angeles`:

1) Create date object

```
var d = new Date();
```

2) Get the local time value

```
var localTime = d.getTime();
```

3) Get the local offset

```
var localOffset = d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
```

4) Obtain UTC

```
var utc = localTime + localOffset;
```

5) Obtain the destination's offset, for America/Loas_Angeles it is UTC -7

```
var offset = -7; 
var ala = utc + (3600000*offset);
```

6) Now ala contains the milis value of America/Los_Angeles. Finally convert it to a new date object if needed:

```
var nd = new Date(ala);
```

Final: Now you can get the miliseconds of the new date object:

```
nd.getTime();
//or
ala;
```